# How to enforce dynamic matching between object properties in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have an object that specifies some properties (**props**), and an array describing the way they should be organized in a grid (**order**).
A position in that order array represents a line of the grid. If the value at a certain index contains the name of a property, it states that it should occupy that entire line, while a value containing a tuple of property names states that those properties should both be displayed side by side.

Here's a use case:

```js
const a: OrderedProperties = {
  props: ['title', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'nickName'],
  order: [
    'title',
    ['firstName', 'lastName'],
    'nickName'
  ]
}
```

However, the current *OrderedProperties* type doesn't check if the values in the order array match property names stated in the props array:

```js
export type OrderGrid = Array<string | [string, string]>;

export type OrderedProperties = {
  props: string[];
  order: OrderGrid
};
```

How can I make typescript dynamically check that the strings passed in the order field match a property name in the props array?

Comment: There's no specific type in TypeScript that works this way; you could write a *generic* type and maybe a helper function that infers the type argument for you, but... why do you want this?  Doesn't the `order` property suffice to give you all the information in `props`?  Why require someone supply redundant information?  Is there a motivating use case?

Comment: You could either annotate the string literals using a generic type parameter or constrain the argument when used in a function. Here's an example with both: https://tsplay.dev/WKvYpm — Does that address your question? If so, I can write it up as an answer — if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jsejcksn That does work as intended, please feel free to write up an answer

Comment: @jcalz You're right, I think I can in fact just change the "props" field to already structure the props as I want to, removing the need for the redundant "order" field. But that's something I need to check with my team, I don't know if there's a legacy reason for this code to be like this. However, despite that, what you say makes sense, feel free to also write an answer

Comment: I don't want to write up an answer to compete with @jsejcksn; any answer I wrote would probably look very similar to that one except I might add a "are you sure you want this" section, which he could add if he wants.  I'll let you two handle this.  Good luck!

Comment: Sure thing, makes sense. Thanks for the comment though, it might come of use anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters to constrain the allowed string literals for each property:

```ts
type OrderGrid<S extends string> = Array<S | [S, S]>;

type OrderedProperties<P extends string, O extends P = P> = {
  props: P[];
  order: OrderGrid<O>;
};
```

You can then specify the allowed string literals in a type annotation (and extraneous values will produce diagnostic errors):

```ts
const a: OrderedProperties<"firstName" | "lastName" | "nickName" | "title"> = {
  props: ["title", "firstName", "lastName", "nickName"],
  order: [
    "title",
    ["firstName", "lastName"],
    "nickName",
  ],
};

const a2: OrderedProperties<"firstName" | "lastName" | "nickName"> = {
  props: ["title", "firstName", "lastName", "nickName"], /* Error (expected)
          ~~~~~~~
  Type '"title"' is not assignable to type '"firstName" | "lastName" | "nickName"'.(2322) */
  order: [
    "title", /* Error
    ~~~~~~~
    Type '"title"' is not assignable to type '"firstName" | "lastName" | "nickName" | ["firstName" | "lastName" | "nickName", "firstName" | "lastName" | "nickName"]'.(2322) */
    ["firstName", "lastName"],
    "nickName",
  ],
};
```

Needing to enumerate the allowed string literals in the type annotation can be tedious. If the object type is intended to be used in a function, you can simply [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the strings in `order` by the ones in `props`, and the compiler can infer for you:

```ts
declare function handleOrderedProps<P extends string, O extends P = P>(
  props: OrderedProperties<P, O>,
): void;

handleOrderedProps({
  props: ["title", "firstName", "lastName", "nickName"],
  order: [
    "title",
    ["firstName", "lastName"],
    "nickName",
  ],
}); // ok

handleOrderedProps({
  props: ["title", "firstName", "lastName", "nickName"],
  order: [
    "title",
    ["firstName", "lastName"],
  ],
}); // "nickName" not present (ok)

handleOrderedProps({
  props: ["title", "firstName", "lastName"],
  order: [
    "title",
    ["firstName", "lastName"],
    "nickName", /* Error (expected)
    ~~~~~~~~~~
    Type '"nickName"' is not assignable to type '"firstName" | "lastName" | "title" | ["firstName" | "lastName" | "title", "firstName" | "lastName" | "title"]'.(2322) */
  ],
});
```

---

As you and @jcalz discussed, one of the properties is redundant — but I can only speculate about which one.

There is potentially semantic information in the data structured as tuple groups (the `order` property) compared to a flat array (the `props` property), and you can trivially flatten a nested array using [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```ts
function getPropsFromOrder<S extends string>(order: OrderGrid<S>): S[] {
  return order.flat() as S[];
}
```

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgEwnA4nAlggPAZShAD2AgDsEBnKc4DEgcwD4oBeKAQTjgEMRcoAfKAG0cAGig4AugwDcAKDmhIsRMggIACnAD2kOMHQRyWDfiKkKVGunriYZ4mUqnWGpqwDecqFDA6w5ABcUBpCkvI+2qpwwfBIqBjYMLJyAL7ycgD0mewkJNrAXMRQXAA2pdoA7upWtHRQpejE3KVBcgDG2iTUJbHR6lq6yAZGWABEAGbocNQAclwAthBjAlBjpVxzi8urYyTo7QDW80srgmMGwKXL7lBePn66QcIXTddj4pPTW6efGz-LT77I4nZaSUTeKBReLBISQnyvK6A+EvKYzYCgj5rf4Y7ZjcEovYHY54iE+AnpBSdbrAEoAJj68QG-mGhmMX3RmN2OK552BJNOt3uvn8zyEiPenzRAKx602uN+a35mPBUEyACooABRThRKAACkIkHaxAQAEoUT4rVAAH52+02yEAFXA0AA5BLlm6oOhKPlaZtyOg6CQuAAja5QYDaKOuqAe6UKnbnHl43bKvFugB0+rpAGY6XSzVB1ZlIdDkLDCZdJWrNTqdHAUQ77SiXcoPTWvT6-QUSuQgyHw5Ho7GOxyZdz5bylcSZ+LEzO5ZO+XPSWtF2mU9Ot7OQXjJNncwWiyWy9aF98k7LU6cCdaifvfpCKRlslAAMJdajcGxQSoABakFAACu5A1H+XBQBMIEkCa6BdIEchIO0GxwNAMFwQYXRQABXBkNccRqJooomA4FiUD+Nh0HY5FOCELAhAw+qQo8ASMsRgx6CMxgaHYDAQmawQAG7aJgGR4QREBEehJFPPqwpsWKnqypuirLteQJrneZJQtEVYPl2HwopenLrhpKq6QiGbPuSEKpGaMhqjk2iHAokkIIR-RyQECmsaKsIqVKV6Yn8O7qTZYK6RWMTCNWbzIheE6adi4VRS+9mOc5e4Cjs-oikYpC0vqrkWnIHleUyPnkH5DwBS8RnBWZ6m3ulkT6XFhkJcZSVqYCqUyveVqPrlWIatqupwAaRoQCa6gWtaLYtm2cYepFYzer6UD5YGwahhG0Cjko7rJUurVnGsRmrKZK4DdeuyNRuIW7hZL1GYeOb5oWxalhlaSOQomHwThdAQMAXHkAAYjoCwyXwhCOJYVH0MxMUcQkmC4AwQkSGEdyQuhwAgXAJB6fEWYTBswD6sWmy4+EaRyEAA)